# How can I navigate from fragment to fragment on button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a few diffrent fragments in my app. In my `HelpFragment` I have a `Button`. What I'm trying to do is that when user press that `Button` then I want them to be navigated to the `ContactFragment` instead.

This is the code I've tried. This code here is crashing my application so clearly it is something wrong here. This code is located in my `MainActivity.java`

```
        Button GoToContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoToContact);
            GoToContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    HelpFragment HelpFragment = new HelpFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            HelpFragment,
                            HelpFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
                }
            });
```

So I have one layout for each and every `Fragment`. So on my `fragment_help` layout is where the button is located. So I want to move them from `fragment_help` over to `fragment_contact`

My code from the fragment_help.xml (Layout)

```
    <Button
    android:text="Go to contact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnGoToContact"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="GoToContact"/>
```

This is my code on the HelpFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {


public HelpFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);
}
```

This is also how my `ContactFragment` look like. This is the automatic generated code when I created the `Fragment`.

Here is the error when I load the app up!

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sveinung.clock, PID: 2304
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sveinung.clock/com.sveinung.clock.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.sveinung.clock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is my whole `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help,  container, false);
    final Button goToContact = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnGoToContact);

    goToContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HelpFragment HelpFragment = new HelpFragment();
            FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                    HelpFragment,
                    HelpFragment.getTag()
            ).commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ClockFragment clockFragment = new ClockFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
            clockFragment,
            clockFragment.getTag()
    ).commit();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_clock) {
        ClockFragment clockFragment = new ClockFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_from_left)
                .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                clockFragment,
                clockFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_world_clock) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*WorldClockFragment worldClockFragment = new WorldClockFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_from_left)
                .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                worldClockFragment,
                worldClockFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();*/

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_timer) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_stopwatch) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_alarm) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        HelpFragment HelpFragment = new HelpFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_from_left)
                .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                        HelpFragment,
                        HelpFragment.getTag()
                ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ContactFragment contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_from_left)
                .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                        contactFragment,
                        contactFragment.getTag()
                ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code:

```
    Button GoToContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoToContact);
        GoToContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                HelpFragment HelpFragment = new HelpFragment();
                FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                        HelpFragment,
                        HelpFragment.getTag()
                ).commit();
            }
        });
```

Needs to be inside of `onCreateView()`. You inflate your layout in `onCreateView()`, find any child `View`s and return your inflated layout. I.e.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);
    final Button goToContact = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnGoToContact);

    goToContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HelpFragment HelpFragment = new HelpFragment();
            FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                    HelpFragment,
                    HelpFragment.getTag()
            ).commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Give that a try.

Comment: If I add that line of code then I get this error: Error:(27, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: @Sveiny That typically means a spelling error or something minor. Alter whatever is giving that error (it'll be something annotated with `@Override`, so `onClick` or `onCreateView`) so it matches its super class.

Comment: I will post in the whole MainActivity.java, with your code onside, so you can take a look, since I don't understand as I'm new to this

Comment: @Sveiny Ahh, the above code should go inside `HelpFragment`, not your `Activity`. The `onCreateView()` method doesn't exist in an `Activity`

Comment: Makes sence, it dose not accept `getSupportFragmentManager();` but if I use `getFragmentManager();` then it works it lets me press the button but it dosen't change to the ContactFragment as I want it to

Comment: @Sveiny Switch `HelpFragment` inside the `replace()` method with a `ContactFragment`

Comment: thanks man it is working now! I appriciate your pacient to help a beginner :)